# Can we use add_action() and apply_filters() in combination?

Tags: php, wordpress

While checking code of some custom plugin in Wordpress, I encountered some code like this :

```
in x.php :-
add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_cod', array( $this, 'extend_cod' ) );

in y.php :-
public function get_form_fields() 
{
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_' . $this->id, array_map( array( $this, 'set_defaults' ), $this->form_fields ) );
}
```

Ideally we use **add_action()/do_action()** in combination. But here they have used **apply_filter() instead of do_action().**

Is it appropriate to use in this way ?
Is there any specific reason/benefit to use this way ?

Comment: What are you trying to archive ?

Comment: I was checking code of some existing plugin and saw this type of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though technically it executes without a problem but WordPress added all this hook helper function to exhibiting the difference in content changes (Filter hook) and logical changes (action hook).

If you closely noted line 404, the function `add_filter` is called inside the function `add_action` even without changing the passed argument so basically these are for just convention and saying to others what's your intention.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/plugin.php#L404

If it is a filter hook there is structural change else if it is action hook there is some logical process that's all.

Kindly read this interesting article to know more.

https://wpsmith.net/2011/the-difference-between-do_action-add_action-and-add_filter/